# Invocar el valor de un método en otro método

Tags: python, python-3.x, poo

Tengo una clase con cuatro métodos. Los tres primeros reciben sus valores como argumentos. En el cuarto método se tiene que hacer condicionales entre estos valores.

> El codigo de ejemplo es el resultado que espero obtener y que sin embargo no consigo.

`ModuloUno.py`

```
class MiClase():
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.valorFinalUno= None
        self.valorFinalDos= None
        self.valorFinalTres= None
        
    def MetodoUno(self, valorUno):
        self.valorFinalUno= valorUno
        return self.valorFinalUno

    def MetodoDos(self, valorDos):
        self.valorFinalDos= valorDos
        return self.valorFinalDos

    def MetodoTres(self, valorTres):
        self.valorFinalTres= valorTres
        return self.valorFinalTres

    def MetodoCuatro(self):
        if self.valorFinalUno== True and self.valorFinalDos== True and self.valorFinalTres==True:
            return "Todos son verdaderos"
        elif self.valorFinalUno== False and self.valorFinalDos== True and self.valorFinalTres== True:
            return "Valor Uno es Falso. ¡Funenlo!"

miClase= MiClase()

miClase.MetodoUno(False)
miClase.MetodoDos(True)
miClase.MetodoTres(True)
print(miClase.MetodoCuatro())
```

Después en otro modulo, dependiendo del resultado obtenido en el cuatro método se hacen otras condiciones.

`ModuloDos.py`

```
from ModuloUno import MiClase

ejm = MiClase()

ejm.MetodoUno(False)
ejm.MetodoDos(True)
ejm.MetodoTres(True)
ejm.MetodoCuatro()

if ejm.MetodoCuatro() == "Valor Uno es Falso. ¡Funenlo!":
    print("Ok a funarlo.")
else:
    print("Hay que darle otra oportunidad.")
```

Aquí me estaría imprimiendo por pantalla `Ok a Funarlo` y lo hace... entonces...

## Dicho todo esto...

¿Qué es lo que podría estar fallando aquí?

`OtroEjemplo.py`

```
class Codigo():    
    def __init__(self):
        self.Noche= 0
        self.Tarde= 0
        self.Mediodia= 0
        self.Mañana= 0
        self.Madrugada= 0
    
    def EvaluacionDiaUno(self, horaDiaUno= True):
        self.horaDiaUno= horaDiaUno
        return self.horaDiaUno
    def EvaluacionDiaDos(self, horaDiaDos= True):
        self.horaDiaDos= horaDiaDos
        return self.horaDiaDos
    def EvaluacionDiaTres(self, horaDiaTres= True):
        self.horaDiaTres= horaDiaTres
        return self.horaDiaTres

    def DiaDefinitivo(self):
        if self.horaDiaUno== True and self.horaDiaDos== True and self.horaDiaTres== True:
            self.Madrugada=+ 1
            return self.Madrugada
        elif self.horaDiaUno== False and self.horaDiaDos== True and self.horaDiaTres== True:
            self.Mañana=+ 1
            return self.Mañana
        elif self.horaDiaUno== True and self.horaDiaDos== True and self.horaDisTres== False:
            self.Mediodia=+ 1
            return self.Mediodia
        elif self.horaDiaUno== False and self.horaDiaDos== True and self.horaDiaTres== False:
            self.Tarde=+ 1
            return self.Tarde
        elif self.horaDiaUno== True and self.horaDiaDos== False and self.horaDiaTres== True:
            self.Noche=+ 1
            return self.Noche
        elif self.horaDiaUno== False and self.horaDiaDos== False and self.horaDisTres== True:
            self.Madrugada=+ 1
            return self.Madrugada
        elif self.horaDiaUno== False and self.horaDiaDos== False and self.horaDiaTres== False:
            self.Noche=+ 1
            return self.Noche
```

En esencia es lo mismo. Pero al llamarlo desde otro modulo, no arroja nada.

`AppEjemplo.py`

```
import tkinter as tk
from OtroEjemplo import Codigo

miFrame = tk.Frame()
resultado= Codigo()


if resultado.Noche != 0 and resultado.Noche>resultado.Tarde or resultado.Noche>resultado.Mediodia or resultado.Noche>resultado.Mañana or resultado.Noche>resultado.Madrugada:
    miLabel= tk.Label(miFrame, text= "Es de noche")
    miLabel.grid()
elif resultado.Tarde != 0 and resultado.Tarde>resultado.Mediodia or resultado.Tarde>resultado.Mañana or resultado.Tarde>resultado.Madrugada:
    miLabel= tk.Label(miFrame, text= "Es de tarde.")
    miLabel.grid()
elif resultado.Mediodia != 0 and resultado.Mediodia>resultado.Mañana or resultado.Mediodia>resultado.Madrugada:
    miLabel= tk.Label(miFrame, text= "Es de mediodia.")
    miLabel.grid()
elif resultado.Mañana != 0 and resultado.Mañana>resultado.Madrugada:
    miLabel= tk.Label(miFrame, text= "Es de mañana")
    miLabel.grid()
elif resultado.Madrugada != 0 and resultado.Madrugada>resultado.Noche:
    miLabel= tk.Label(miFrame, text= "Es de madrugada")
    miLabel.grid()

print(resultado.Madrugada)
print(resultado.Mañana)
print(resultado.Mediodia)
print(resultado.Tarde)
print(resultado.Noche)

miFrame.mainloop()
```

Al imprimir por pantalla el resultado de los atributos todos marcan 0 ¿por que no esta leyendo las condiciones del primer modulo y a raíz de ese valor comparar en el otro modulo para que me imprima por pantalla si es de día noche o lo que sea?

## Actualizacion

Puse los atributos en el inicializador.
Cree un método que validaba si todos los atributos tenían su valor respectivo.
Llame a ese método desde los métodos principales
Obtuve el resultado que queria...

El código quedo así:

```
class Codigo():    
    def __init__(self):
        self.Noche= 0
        self.Tarde= 0
        self.Mediodia= 0
        self.Mañana= 0
        self.Madrugada= 0
        
        self.horaDiaUno= None
        self.horaDiaDos= None
        self.horaDiaTres= None
    
    def EvaluacionDiaUno(self, horaDiaUno):
        self.horaDiaUno= horaDiaUno
        self.ValidarDia()
        return self.horaDiaUno
    def EvaluacionDiaDos(self, horaDiaDos):
        self.horaDiaDos= horaDiaDos
        self.ValidarDia()
        return self.horaDiaDos
    def EvaluacionDiaTres(self, horaDiaTres):
        self.horaDiaTres= horaDiaTres
        self.ValidarDia()
        return self.horaDiaTres
    
    def ValidarDia(self):
        if self.horaDiaUno != None and self.horaDiaDos != None and self.horaDiaTres != None:
            self.DiaDefinitivo()
        else:
            pass

    def DiaDefinitivo(self):
        if self.horaDiaUno== True and self.horaDiaDos== True and self.horaDiaTres== True:
            self.Madrugada=+ 1
            return self.Madrugada
        elif self.horaDiaUno== False and self.horaDiaDos== True and self.horaDiaTres== True:
            self.Mañana=+ 1
            return self.Mañana
        elif self.horaDiaUno== True and self.horaDiaDos== True and self.horaDisTres== False:
            self.Mediodia=+ 1
            return self.Mediodia
        elif self.horaDiaUno== False and self.horaDiaDos== True and self.horaDiaTres== False:
            self.Tarde=+ 1
            return self.Tarde
        elif self.horaDiaUno== True and self.horaDiaDos== False and self.horaDiaTres== True:
            self.Noche=+ 1
            return self.Noche
        elif self.horaDiaUno== False and self.horaDiaDos== False and self.horaDisTres== True:
            self.Madrugada=+ 1
            return self.Madrugada
        elif self.horaDiaUno== False and self.horaDiaDos== False and self.horaDiaTres== False:
            self.Noche=+ 1
            return self.Noche
```

Al final no me imprime el `Label` correspondiente pero creo que es un problema mas de tkinter no he implementado bien, o de la logica, porque por pantalla si me imprime el valor `1` de `self.Madrugada`.

Comment: No se ve que en ningún momento hayas llamado a algún metodo `.EvaluaciónDia*` ¿Falta código?

Comment: Supuse que al establecer los valores de sus atributos entre los paréntesis no era necesario...

Comment: Es que en ningún lado se ve que esté dando valores a los atributos de `resultado`. No sé a qué te refieres con _los valores entre los paréntesis_.

Comment: `def EvaluacionDia*(self, horaDiaUno= True)` <--- a ese argumento... 
¿No se supone que al estar todos `True` en el método `DiaDefinitivo` se le añadiría el valor `1`  al atributo `self.Madrugada`?

Comment: Pero es que no has llamado a `DiaDefinitivo` en ningún momento. Además, no existen los atributos `horaDia*` hasta que no llames los métodos `EvaluacionDia*`, con lo que dará error `DiaDefinitivo`. Tal vez deberías replantearte mejor lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Ah, cierto... ahí si que no entiendo como hacerlo. Si lo llamo cada vez en los métodos `EvaluacionDia*` no hace la comparación porque todavía no tiene los tres valores... los atributos `horaDia*` si existen ¿no?, se crean en cada método, no es necesario que estén en el constructor ¿no?

Comment: Intente hacer un cuarto método que validara si ya estaban los tres valores de los métodos `EvaluacionDia`  y de ahi llamr al metodo `DiaDefinitivo` pero no me funciono...

Comment: No hace falta que todos los atributos se creen en el inicializador, pero sí que tienen que haberse creado antes de chequear sus valores.

Comment: Los estoy creando en los tres primeros métodos y en el cuarto checando sus valores ¿con eso vale, no? Y por lo otro, entonces debería crear el quinto método para validar y desde ahí llamar al método que hace la revisión supongo ¿no? Creo que intentare eso y a ver que tal me va...

Comment: No entiendo bien la lógica que intentas crear. Voy a ponerte tal como yo crearía la clase `Codigo`.

Comment: Modifique el código con algunas de las cosas que me mencionaste y aplica el quinto método para validar. No me imprime el `Label`  correspondiente en el `Frame` pero si me da el valor agregado 1 al final...  esta actualizado en el post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin entender muy bien la lógica que estás intentando crear, la clase `Codigo` tiene atributos que no están creados cuando invocas al método `DiaDefinitivo`. En realidad, sobran atributos y sobran métodos.

Una posible reescritura:

```py
class Codigo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.noche = 0
        self.tarde = 0
        self.mediodia = 0
        self.mañana = 0
        self.madrugada = 0

    def Evaluacion(self, *, horaDiaUno=True, horaDiaDos=True, horaDiaTres=True):

        a, b, c = horaDiaUno, horaDiaDos, horaDiaTres

        if (a, b, c) == (True, True, True):
            self.madrugada = 1
        elif (a, b, c) == (False, True, True):
            self.mañana = 1
        elif (a, b, c) == (True, True, False):
            self.mediodia = 1
        elif (a, b, c) == (False, True, False):
            self.tarde = 1
        elif (a, b, c) == (True, False, True):
            self.noche = 1
        elif (a, b, c) == (True, False, False):
            self.madrugada = 1
        elif (a, b, c) == (False, False, False):
            self.noche = 1
```

Los argumentos del método `Evaluación` se invocan por nombre, por ejemplo: `Codigo().Evaluación(horaDiaTres=False)`. Por defecto, los tres días son `True`. No sé si es correcto o no.

Una mejora para no tener tantos `ifs`, sería usar un diccionario:

```py
from enum import Enum


class HoraDia(Enum):
    NOCHE = 0
    TARDE = 1
    MEDIODIA = 2
    MAÑANA = 3
    MADRUGADA = 4


class Codigo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.horaDia: HoraDia = HoraDia.NOCHE

    def Evaluacion(self, *, horaDiaUno=True, horaDiaDos=True, horaDiaTres=True):

        horas = {
            (True, True, True): HoraDia.MADRUGADA,
            (False, True, True): HoraDia.MAÑANA,
            (True, True, False): HoraDia.MEDIODIA,
            (False, True, False): HoraDia.TARDE,
            (True, False, True): HoraDia.NOCHE,
            (True, False, False): HoraDia.MADRUGADA,
            (False, False, False): HoraDia.NOCHE,
        }

        self.horaDia = horas[(horaDiaUno, horaDiaDos, horaDiaTres)]
```

Desconozco si te encajaría o no. Añade en comentarios lo que consideres.

Comment: Me gusta. En realidad este código es solo de ejemplo... tendría como ver como implementarlo con el que estoy trabajando y ver si funciona. Muchas gracias por todo la molestia de responder, me has permitido expandir mi horizonte de visualización respecto a como estoy trabajando el programa:)